# Parsing 12-hour times using lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm trying to get my head around parsing 12-hour times using lubridate. If I run

```
library(lubridate)
times <- c("1:30 AM",  "6:29 AM",  "6:59 AM",  "9:54 AM", "2:45 PM")
hm(times)
```

I get

```
[1] "1H 30M 0S" "6H 29M 0S" "6H 59M 0S" "9H 54M 0S" "2H 45M 0S"
```

Note that the AM/PM designation is not used. However, if if the time strings also includes a date then the parsing works

```
ymd_hm(paste("01-01-01", times))
[1] "2001-01-01 01:30:00 UTC" "2001-01-01 06:29:00 UTC"
[3] "2001-01-01 06:59:00 UTC" "2001-01-01 09:54:00 UTC"
[5] "2001-01-01 14:45:00 UTC"
```

It seems to me that the time parsing functions: `hm`, `hms`, ... doesn't recognize the AM/PM, but the date functions do. Is it possible to allow for 12-hour parsing without going through the dates?

[I know I can do this by parsing the strings but I was wondering it it was possible within `lubidate`]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two objects belong to different classes each one designed for a specific purpose.

With the first function you create a `period` class object. This kind of class if designed to represent times, like time of a race, or "how many hours Bolt runs 100 meters?" 0 hours 0 minutes 9 seconds 58 and so on.

See:

```
a <- hm(times)
class(a)
[1] "Period"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"
```

The second object with the function `ymd_hm` creates an object of class:

```
b <- ymd_hm(paste("01-01-01", times))
class(b)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

This class of object is designed to represent "time", in the sense of Gregorian calendar (or maybe other kind of calendars). It does parse also AM/PM that are vital to differentiate hours of the day in a 12 hours clock.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose it's not possible to force a POSIXct interpretation of the times directly

Comment: @ekstroem I think so.